# How do I use querySelectorAll when using pagination?

Tags: javascript, datatables

In my dashboard, I'm using the datatables plugin to display records from a database.

At the end of every row, there is an edit button that when you click on, a modal pops up where you can update the data of that table row.

So I used `document.querySelectorAll('#editBtn')` to select all edit buttons so I can loop through them and add a click event listener to each one.

The problem I'm facing is when I go to the second page, new records are displayed and I don't know how I can select the new buttons.

This is my code:

```
var editBtn = document.querySelectorAll('#editBtn');
editBtn.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        alert('It works!');
    })
})
```

Comment: Instead of put this code directly use a function and call it every time dataTable data is load.

Comment: How do I detect when the dataTable data is loaded?

Comment: How data is load ?

Comment: Just a sidenote, but **ids must be unique**, you would be better of using a `class` if you happen to have control over that. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Comment: Or better (for me and your idle) use `data-attribute` :) [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: Look at the example [here](http://live.datatables.net/mutavegi/6/edit) for code which supports selecting all checkboxes across multiple pages. Basically, you use the DataTables API to access every node, because the DOM only gives you access to one page of (visible) rows - as you have seen.

Comment: If you cannot adapt that example to your needs, maybe you can [edit] your question to show your attempt and where you get stuck. (Also there are several old questions on SO for this exact question - so maybe one of the many answers there can help you.)